# Is is possible for a generic method to use different (generic) objects based on its type parameter?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to simplify a stack based interpreter with different stacks for each data type.

Essentially I have a bunch of instructions which look like this:

```
class Interpreter {
    Stack<int> IntStack;
    Stack<float> FloatStack;
    Stack<char> CharStack;
    // ... Continued for various other types.
}

class PushInt : Instruction {
    Interpreter interpreter;
    int value;

    void Execute() {
        interpreter.IntStack.Push(value);
    }
}

class PopInt : Instruction {
    Interpreter interpreter;

    void Execute() {
        interpreter.IntStack.Pop();
    }
}
```

I have the same thing for `PushFloat`, `PopFloat`, `PushChar`, `PopChar`, etc

This screams "Generics" to me, what i'd love to do is define a `Push<T>` and `Pop<T>` instead. But I run into an issue here:

```
class Push<T> : Instruction {
    Interpreter interpreter;
    T value;

    void Execute() {
        interpreter.[What on earth goes here?].Push(value);
    }
}

class Pop<T> : Instruction {
    Interpreter interpreter;

    void Execute() {
        interpreter.[What on earth goes here?].Pop();
    }
}
```

I thought, surely there must be a way to define `Interpreter.Push<T>(value)`, but I end up with the same problem inside that method - i'm not sure how I can choose the correct stack based on the generic type parameter without some mess of casting.

### Stuff I've tried Already:

One solution I've tried that sort of does work is to use static classes:

```
public static class ArgumentStack<T> {
    public static Stack<T> Stack;

    public static void Push(T value) {
        Stack.Push(value);
    }

    public static T Pop() {
        return Stack.Pop();
    }
}

public class Push<T> : Instruction {
    T value;

    public override void Execute() {
        ArgumentStack<T>.Push(Value);
    }
}

public class Pop<T> : Instruction {
    public override void Execute() {
        ArgumentStack<T>.Pop();
    }
}
```

But the problem with this is that if multiple interpreters are in use at once the whole thing starts to break down because only one instance of each stack type exists and they're shared across all interpreters.

It's frustrating because the static approach is pretty much exactly what I want in terms of usage, I just wish I could do this inside each Interpreter object rather than at the class level.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a cool question. +1

Comment: You should also parameterise your Stack (Stack<T>) instead of declaring it as  intStack, charStack, immediate benefit is that there are separate static methods for each closed type (so Stack<int> and Stack<char> will get separate copies of same method). Also look for variance, you can implement interfaces with  pop (covariant) and push (contra variant).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, generics are the key here. It seems like you simply want a class (Interpreter) to have a Stack property within it of an unknown type. From there you want to be able to add and remove items from that Stack using Push and Pop like this:

```
public class Interpreter<T>
{
    public Stack<T> TypeStack { get; set; }

    public Interpreter()
    {
        if (this.TypeStack == null)
        {
            this.TypeStack = new Stack<T>();
        }
    }
    public void Push(T value)
    {
        this.TypeStack.Push(value);
    }

    public void Pop()
    {
        this.TypeStack.Pop();
    }
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
  var interpreter = new Interpreter<int>();
  interpreter.Push(5);
  interpreter.Pop();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The problem with this though is that I think each interpreter would only be able to deal with one stack type right? Each interpreter in my project needs to be able to handle a wide variety of stack types. I've posted a solution that seems to work for now (might express more clearly what i'm trying to achieve) hopefully someone's got a nicer solution though.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution i'm reasonably happy with. But will leave the question open in case someone has something prettier.

I defined a static dictionary in the static generic class that maps interpreters to individual stacks, then defined an interpreter method which retrieve the correct generic stack. Code example below:

```
public static class ArgumentStack<T> {
    public static Dictionary<Interpreter, Stack<T>> Stacks;
}


public class Interpreter {
    public Stack<T> GetStack<T>() {
        return ArgumentStack<T>.Stacks[this];
    }
}


public class Push<T> : Instruction {
    Interpreter interpreter;
    T value;

    public override void Execute() {
        interpreter.GetStack<T>().Push(Value);
    }
}

public class Pop<T> : Instruction {
    Interpreter interpreter;

    public override void Execute() {
        interpreter.GetStack<T>().Pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: In response to the other answer you said that you needed each interpreter to work with multiple stacks. But in this case the interpreter still has one stack. It's just stored in a different class. If there's one stack for every interpreter, why not just move it back into the interpreter? That's a lot cleaner and gets rid of the static dependency. Having all of this depend on a static class will make it harder to unit test.

Comment: @ScottHannen in the code above, the interpreter has one stack for each type T, rather than just one stack because of the Generic instances of the static class. ArgumentStack<int>, ArgumentStack<float>, ArgumentStack<string> etc.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. My understanding was that the interpreter needed to support different stacks for different types. This is a way of handling it. To be precise, it will have one stack for each type that is added.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach you might be able to adapt. It appears that you want to be able to work with many different types while routing them each to their own stacks according to their type. (It's hard to understand quite where you're going with it, but I'll leave that to you.)

```
public class Interpreter
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Stack> _stacksByType = new Dictionary<Type, Stack>();

    public void Push<T>(T item) 
    {
        if (!_stacksByType.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            _stacksByType.Add(typeof(T), new Stack());
        }
        _stacksByType[typeof(T)].Push(item);
    }

    public T Pop<T>()
    {
        // If we pop an empty stack it throws an InvalidOperationException
        // so I'm throwing the same exception if there's no corresponding stack.
        if (!_stacksByType.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("There is nothing in the stack.");
        return (T)_stacksByType[typeof(T)].Pop();
    }
}
```

This allows `Interpreter` to encapsulate all of its various stacks. When you `Push` an item, it places it into a `Stack` according to its type. If the stack doesn't exist then it creates it.

When you `Pop`, it will pop from the stack according to type. If the stack for that type doesn't exist, it will throw the same exception as when the stack is empty.

Because we're managing type safety by controlling which `Stack` an item goes into we don't need the generic `Stack<T>`.

This encapsulation also allows us to avoid this:

```
interpreter.IntStack.Push(value);
```

It's better if classes outside of `Interpreter` don't know how it's managing all of this internally. Instead of telling the class which stack to put a value in, we can just give it the value and let it figure that out.